# Matlab: matrix not getting updated in loop

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab. I have an array, I am finding the min element in the matrix and then making the corresponding row and column of matrix as 1. In the first loop it works perfect But for the next loops the matrix is not getting updated.

Code:

```
data=[1.00000000 0.53137106 0.85595882 0.66829640 0.23856533 0.45405844 0.54347968 0.56774586 0.23837982 0.62409687; 
0.53137106 1.00000000 0.28491443 0.83557534 0.58327866 0.53124779 0.18295255 0.30800611 0.88819402 0.82852000 ;
0.85595882 0.28491443 1.00000000 0.88712496 0.53283900 0.93776625 0.18187943 0.25401449 0.46880579 0.86628407 ;
0.66829640 0.83557534 0.88712496 1.00000000 0.73516506 0.32148027 0.87524909 0.85505933 0.72357458 0.09848434 ;
0.23856533 0.58327866 0.53283900 0.73516506 1.00000000 0.70343286 0.51693362 0.51673573 0.27955368 0.72713149 ;
0.45405844 0.53124779 0.93776625 0.32148027 0.70343286 1.00000000 0.68939388 0.84967077 0.40466678 0.31867197 ;
0.54347968 0.18295255 0.18187943 0.87524909 0.51693362 0.68939388 1.00000000 0.21098818 0.86957568 0.86703879 ;
0.56774586 0.30800611 0.25401449 0.85505933 0.51673573 0.84967077 0.21098818 1.00000000 0.79130369 0.81940556 ;
0.23837982 0.88819402 0.46880579 0.72357458 0.27955368 0.40466678 0.86957568 0.79130369 1.00000000 0.88794363 ;
0.62409687 0.82852000 0.86628407 0.09848434 0.72713149 0.31867197 0.86703879 0.81940556 0.88794363 1.00000000 ];
ptr=1;

for k= 1:9
 k
%find min ele, its row and column no:
[minNumRow, minIndexRow] = min(data);
[minNum, row] = min(minNumRow);
col = minIndexCol(row);
row 
col
minNum
%storing it in cluster array
cluster{ptr}={strcat(int2str(row),', ',int2str(col))};
ptr=ptr+1;
%make eles of merged objects as 1
    for i=1:10
     data(row)=1; 
     row=row+10;
    end
    for i= ((col*10)-10): (col*10)
     data(i)=1;
    end
 data
end
```

Help please!

Comment: Note also that in the data the minimum value (0.0985) exists two times. Both given answers only find the occurence in cell (10,4), but it's also in (4,10). Do you want to take care of that as well or is one sufficient?

Comment: @SebastianHöffner, Good point. Thanks.

Comment: yes 0.0985 appears twice. I need to  find the min element only once and for the second element, I need to remove the  column/row from matrix.

Comment: @SebastianHöffner this is a limitation of the `min` function. If there are several identical minimum values, only the index of the first one found is returned.

Comment: @excaza I know, I just wanted to point this out, since it was not clear what exactly nikhilk was looking for.

Comment: Just to let you know guys, I am trying to do this: http://www.docdroid.net/k0pe/singlelink-clustering-sheet1.pdf.html where after every loop i need to merge the column/row names too

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got it right, but I think you need this,

```
data = randi(9, [5 5]); % put your data instead
[colData, column] = min(data);
[~, row] = min(colData);
data(:,column(row)) = 1;
data(row,:) = 1;
```

This changes the row and column of min to the value of `1`.

Comment: @nikhilk, Isn't this what you need?

Comment: Doesn't `[~,ind] = min(min(Data))` only return the row index?

Comment: [~,ind] = min(min(Data)) returned me row index. I want to make corresponding column as 1 too.

Comment: Yes, I'm so sorry, let me change it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loops.

Based on your sample data:

```
[~, linidx] = min(data(:)); % Returns linear index of minimum
[row, col] = ind2sub(size(data),linidx); % Convert linear index to subscripts

% Set row & column to 1
data(row,:) = 1;
data(:,col) = 1;
```

See the documentation for [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) and [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) for more information. Chiefly:

> MATLAB stores matrices and arrays not in the shape that they appear
>   when displayed in the MATLAB Command Window, but as a single column of
>   elements.

Which we leverage by using `data(:)` in the `min()` to obtain the index of our minimum value.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments above by Sebastian, if multiple identical minimums are present this method will only return the location of the first one. This is a behavior inherent to the `min` function, so you will have to implement your own logic to find identical values (within the tolerances of [floating point errors](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)) and modify as necessary.